# login redirects infinitly on subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a subdomain at:
kezblu.mysite.com.

It is actually at mysite.com/kezblu

I have code that will ask a user to login if they are not:

```
protected void HandleLoginRedirect()
{
    if (IsRequestedPage("Login") && Authorization.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
    else if (!Authorization.IsAuthenticated() && !IsRequestedPage("Login"))
    {
        string fileName = this.Page.Request.Url.ToString();
        fileName = fileName.Remove(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx?redirect=" + fileName);
    }
}


    public bool IsRequestedPage(string pageName)
    {
        return Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("/" + pageName + ".aspx");
    }
```

The problem is of I go to kezblu.mysite.com/kezblu

I end up with:

```
http://kezblu.mysite.com/kezblu/Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=Login.aspx?redirect=default.aspx
```

I also noticed when I sign out, even if I was at kezblu.mysite.com/somewhere.aspx

It redirects me to the above.

What is wrong with my code?

I do not get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the domain of the authentication cookie so that it works on your subdomain as well.

When you request a page in your subdomain, if you are not authenticated, it redirects you to the login page on your domain.  You authenticate and the server sends down an authentication cookie that is only for the domain; not the subdomain.  You then get redirected back to the page that you came from in the subdomain, but your browser doesn't send the authentication cookie.  This causes your subdomain page again to redirect back to the login page.  This time, your browser does send the cookie, and the login page automatically redirects you back, but your browser won't send the cookie and so the cycle begins.

To fix this, set the domain of the cookie to `".domain.com"` rather than `"domain.com"`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="..."
    domain=".domain.com" /><!-- Not "domain.com" -->
</authentication>
```

Comment: I am not using this so that is not the problem.